# Would an ICBM be visible?

Tags: optics, estimation, rocket-science

From the ground, would an ICBM warhead on terminal approach be visible to the naked eye before it detonated?  I'm thinking it would be at reentry speed so would look like a big fireball.

Comment: lol, the behavior and appearance of an object reentering the atmosphere isn't mainstream physics??

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have seen  [pictures of incoming MIRVs](https://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/5/5f/Peacekeeper-missile-testing.jpg). They do indeed look like meteors heading down to Kwajalein.